# Css Files dont work On Eclipse

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I am learning Java on eclipse (JavaFx), and I have a problem where I want to create a css file in Eclipse, but when i type `.root {  }` it gives me an error.

My error says :

```
'Syntax error on token "." interface expected'.
```

As you see in the screenshots, I tried to download a bunch of plugins but none worked or helped me to find a solution. I searched online for 2 hours to find solution but can't find one. I hope you will help and thank you for giving your time to read this.

[Where the error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agKWz.png)

[image: Error]

[My plugins (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGaKu.png)

[image: My plugins (part 1)]

[My plugins (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpVAP.png)

[image: My plugins (part 2)]

Comment: For whatever reason, Eclipse seems to think your CSS file is Java source code.

Comment: hello thanks but what should i do?

Comment: How are you creating this file?

Comment: right click on my package then new, others , in the folder web i find CSS FILE i click next i give it a name like this Hello.css then i finish if you want a screen shot tell me sir :)

Comment: At some point did you try to open a Java source file with the CSS editor, and then get prompted to try and fix it? Check your **File Associations** preference page for what the default editor is for `*.css` files.